# Wordpress non-www to www redirects all urls to home instead that url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, no-www

My all non www urls redirects to my homepage

This is my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question? could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to force everything to use www, then this should do the trick.

```
# Needed before any rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect HTTP without www to HTTP with www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Redirect HTTPS without www to HTTPS with www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

## 301 Redirects can go after this
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget set your domain in `wp_options` table or in settings.

[image]

Also, drop this lines in your `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^opcito.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.opcito.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Hope it'll help you :)